# Returning value from a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, google-chrome-app, indexeddb

I am working with angularjs and chrome app. (Beginner in this scope)
I am using idb library of promise for indexedDB.
What I want is to get the all categories from store and return them in a controller function. my code look //check for support

```
     if (!('indexedDB' in window)) {
        console.log('This browser doesn\'t support IndexedDB');
      }

      const dbPromise = idb.open('test-db4', 2, function(upgradeDb) {
          if (!upgradeDb.objectStoreNames.contains('category')) {
              var category = upgradeDb.createObjectStore('category', {keyPath: 'cat_id', autoIncrement: true});
              category.createIndex('cat_name', 'cat_name', {unique: true});
              category.createIndex('cat_addedby', 'cat_addedby', {unique: false});
          }
      }
```

My Controller and factory Look like this

Factory :

```
app.factory('database', function(){
    var factory = {};
    factory.allCategories = function(){
        val = [];
        val = dbPromise.then(db => {
            return db.transaction('category')
              .objectStore('category').getAll();
          }).then(function(allObjs){ return allObjs});
          return val;
    }
    return factory;
});
```

Controller :

```
 app.controller('catalogController', function($scope, database){
    var cat = database.allCategories().then(function(allobjs){return allobjs});
   console.log(cat);
});
```

I have tried everything but it still returns the promise not the result of the store which is actually an array.
I have searched a lot but I was not able to find any answer which meets this..
Thanks.

Comment: `then` always returns a promise. You need to use a function _inside_ `then` to get at the promise's inner value. Right now, the `then` you have in your controller is completely redundant.

Comment: i.e. `database.allCategories().then(console.log)` will log the values you seek

Comment: console.log is printing the array but the problem is that I want to store these values in a golbal variable but I am not able to do it... @JaromandaX

Comment: @JLRishe Can you please tell me how can that function return that value...

Comment: at this stage I want a controller function that returns all the categories in an array form... but I am not able to achieve that ...

Comment: read the dupe - you need to know how to deal with asynchrony